# Unresolved reference: textView

Tags: java, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-adapter

I'm trying to create a recyclerView, but when I try to reference my textView I get an error that says Unresolved Reference: textViewTitle, I have tried many ways and I could not, I appreciate your wise help.

```
class RecyclerAdapter(private val userList: ArrayList<Sitios> = ArrayList()) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        //Unresolved reference: textViewTitle
        holder.itemView.textViewTitle.text = userList[position].description
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = userList.size
```

Comment: Is there a `textViewTitle` in `card_view.xml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`holder.itemView` is the `View` you pass into your `ViewHolder` class when `onCreateViewHolder` runs. It's just a normal `View`, and there's no field called `textViewTitle` in that class, which is what you're trying to reference with `holder.itemView.textViewTitle` - that's why it's saying the reference is unresolved

What you probably want to do is *find a `TextView` with that ID within `itemView`'s hierarchy*, so you need to do

```
holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewTitle)
```

or whatever the ID is. But typically, people will put fields in the `ViewHolder` class instead, set them by doing the lookup once, and then you can just access them like you're trying to do:

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    lateinit var textViewTitle : TextView
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false)
    // or you could make the TextView a val in the ViewHolder's constructor and just pass it in instead of setting it after creation
    val holder = ViewHolder(v)
    holder.textViewTitle = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewTitle)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    // now the reference is a field on the ViewHolder
    holder.textViewTitle.text = userList[position].description
}
```

this is better because `onBindViewHolder` runs every time a new item scrolls into view, so you don't want to be doing lots of `findViewById`s when you can just do it once

---

If you're doing it the field way, like up there, instead of making the view references constructor parameters (which can get messy when you have a few) I'd write it more like this:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v).apply {
        textViewTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle)
        // and any other views you need to set up
    }
}
```

it looks pretty neat, especially with several views!